# H2 junit test not creating table and not populating data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2

Just experimenting with using H2 as a testing database for unit tests. The app works but failing to find the schema-h2.sql file in src/test/resources.  The error:

> ServletContext resource [/schema-h2.sql] defined by 'spring.datasource.schema' does not exist

I can define it this way in src/test/resources/application.properties and it throws no error...however, it seems to be creating the table based on my Entity object.  I can tell this because it's putting a primary key in there when the table definition in schema-h2.sql has none. Config stuff below...

> file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/schema-h2.sql

contents of schema-h2.sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE translog
(
   objectid numeric(18,0),
   translog_type varchar(3),
   primary_relation numeric(18,0),
   transaction_type int,
   ADB_SUBJECT varchar(255),
   ADB_SEQUENCE int NOT NULL,
   ADB_SET_SEQUENCE int,
   ADB_TIMESTAMP datetime,
   ADB_OPCODE int NOT NULL,
   ADB_UPDATE_ALL int,
   ADB_REF_OBJECT varchar(64),
   ADB_L_DELIVERY_STATUS char(1),
   ADB_L_CMSEQUENCE decimal(28,0),
   ADB_TRACKINGID varchar(40)
);
```

entity:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="translog")
public class Translog {

    @Id
    @Column(name="objectid")
    private Long objectid;
    @Column(name="translog_type")
    private String translogType;
    @Column(name="primary_relation")
    private Long primaryRelation;
    @Column(name="transaction_type")
    private Integer transactionType;
    @Column(name="ADB_SUBJECT")
    private String adbSubject;
    @Column(name="ADB_SEQUENCE")
    private Integer adbSequence;
    @Column(name="ADB_SET_SEQUENCE")
    private Integer adbSetSequence;
    @Column(name="ADB_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date adbTimestamp;
    @Column(name="ADB_OPCODE")
    private Integer adbOpcode;
    @Column(name="ADB_UPDATE_ALL")
    private Integer adbUpdateAll;
    @Column(name="ADB_REF_OBJECT")
    private String adbRefObject;
    @Column(name="ADB_L_DELIVERY_STATUS")
    private String adbLDeliveryStatus;
    @Column(name="ADB_L_CMSEQUENCE")
    private BigInteger adbLCmsequence;
    @Column(name="ADB_TRACKINGID")
    private String adbTrackingid;

    ...getters ane setters
```

properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.schema=schema-h2.sql
spring.datasource.data=data-h2.sql
#spring.datasource.schema=file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/schema-h2.sql
#spring.datasource.data=file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/data-h2.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

The stack trace when asking it to find the h2 setup:

```
        2018-03-15 09:50:13.278 ERROR 13944 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.config.ResourceNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/schema-h2.sql] defined by 'spring.datasource.schema' does not exist
    ...cut out for brevity
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.config.ResourceNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/schema-h2.sql] defined by 'spring.datasource.schema' does not exist
    ...cut out for brevity
    ... 52 more

...

2018-03-15 10:12:10.094  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.i.ScriptUtils                    : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/schema-h2.sql]
2018-03-15 10:12:10.102  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.i.ScriptUtils                    : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/schema-h2.sql] in 8 ms.
2018-03-15 10:12:10.105  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.i.ScriptUtils                    : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/data-h2.sql]
2018-03-15 10:12:10.124  INFO 10040 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.i.ScriptUtils                    : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/src/test/resources/data-h2.sql] in 19 ms.
2018-03-15 10:12:10.293  INFO 10040 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-15 10:12:10.318 DEBUG 10040 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
    excludeUnlistedClasses: true
    JTA datasource: null
    Non JTA datasource: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@3ea75b05{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1; username=sa; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; useStatementFacade=true; }
    Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
    PU root URL: file:/C:/workspace/DatabaseAdapter/target/test-classes/
    Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
    Validation Mode: AUTO
    Jar files URLs []
    Managed classes names [
        com.ezcorp.databaseadapter.domain.Translog]
    Mapping files names []
    Properties []

.......

2018-03-15 10:12:11.306 DEBUG 10040 --- [           main] o.h.l.p.b.s.LoadPlanTreePrinter          : LoadPlan(entity=com.ezcorp.databaseadapter.domain.Translog)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=com.ezcorp.databaseadapter.domain.Translog, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=com.ezcorp.databaseadapter.domain.Translog)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=com.ezcorp.databaseadapter.domain.Translog)
          - SQL table alias mapping - translog0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {objectid1_0_0_}

.......

2018-03-15 10:12:14.728  INFO 10040 --- [           main] c.e.d.DbAdapterApplicationTests          : Started DbAdapterApplicationTests in 8.409 seconds (JVM running for 9.466)
2018-03-15 10:12:14.785 DEBUG 10040 --- [           main] c.e.d.d.TranslogRepository               : [DB_ADAPT] REPOSITORY.getTranslogs - gather data from ezsystem for processing: sql=select TOP 2 * from p_t_ezsystem_translog where ADB_L_DELIVERY_STATUS = 'N' order by ADB_TIMESTAMP ASC
2018-03-15 10:12:14.795 DEBUG 10040 --- [           main] c.e.d.d.TranslogRepository               : [DB_ADAPT] REPOSITORY.getTranslogs - got (0) records
2018-03-15 10:12:14.821  INFO 10040 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.c.n.e.InstanceInfoFactory            : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-03-15 10:12:14.833  INFO 10040 --- [       Thread-7] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Unregistering application unknown with eureka with status DOWN
2018-03-15 10:12:14,917 Thread-7 WARN Unable to register Log4j shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down. Using SimpleLogger
```

Comment: try `spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema-h2.sql`

Comment: Jaiwo99...that works as far as finding the files.  Thank you as it's much better than hard coding a path.  Now, however, the other issue is present still...it appears to have both run the create and the inserts per the logs.  But when the queries are run via the test, it does not work...meaning that it finds zero records.  it should find 5 records...any idea what is happening to my data when running from a junit test?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post a finding. I do not think I have a problem since implementing Jaiwo99's suggestion.  I discovered by changing the query..made it very simple:

> select * from translog

Since I get results from this, my issue is clearly not config but a limitation in the way H2 does SQL vs SQL Server.  I should have checked this first   :-)